# SQL count number of rows for 5 days and add to count_concat

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores record each time a email is send through my app, Now I am trying to develop a statistic page for the app with highcharts. I am trying to tbl_template_log count number of entries for past 5 days and add these values to group_concat so i can feed the results into the graph.

my Query:

```
SELECT group_concat(count(tbl_template_log.templog_id)) as 'stats_data' FROM tbl_template_log
              WHERE DATE(tbl_template_log.send_date) < DATE(NOW())
              AND DATE(tbl_template_log.send_date) > DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 6 DAY
```

I get an SQL error:

```
1111 - Invalid use of group function
```

I assume this refers to the combination of group_concat() and count()
is there any way to construct a query which will do both count number of rows per day and add these values to group_concat....or perhaps some other way to do this operation...?

Comment: if you are counting data then just remove `group_concat` and add a `group by tbl_template_log.send_date`. Its better to select the same column while doing group by.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to tbl_template_log count number of entries for past 5 days , then why not use as below using the `group by`. If you save date info as datetime then use `date(tbl_template_log.send_date) as send_date` and finally `group by send_date`

```
SELECT 
tbl_template_log.send_date,
count(tbl_template_log.templog_id) as `stats_data` 
FROM tbl_template_log
WHERE 
DATE(tbl_template_log.send_date) < DATE(NOW())
AND 
DATE(tbl_template_log.send_date) > DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 6 DAY
group by tbl_template_log.send_date
```

Comment: Hi thx for your answer, but the outcome of this query is just 1 for each row so i get plenty of 1's for each day and i need to add all these 1 into one number for each day

Comment: well count() with group by should not show plenty of 1 for each day, make sure you do group by `date(tbl_template_log.send_date)` as in the comment since you are saving data as datetime.

Comment: Here is a demo of this behaviour http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b350/2 , adding a different alias name for the date col http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b350/3

Answer (score 0):

just try!

I think you need this :

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT
(tbl_template_log.templog_id) AS stats_data 
FROM 
(
SELECT COUNT(stats_data)
FROM tbl_template_log
WHERE DATE(tbl_template_log.send_date) < DATE(NOW())
AND DATE(tbl_template_log.send_date) > DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 6 DAY
)test
```